# Asking questions about DMOJ on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about DMOJ.ca?

That is also a programming site, however, there seems to be no tag for it.

I also created a proposition about this on Area 51, however, it got closed saying:

> There is already a site for this called StackOverflow, concerning professional programming developers.

Again, this, in my opinion, is wrong, as there are no tags for it. And, if I *can't* ask questions about this on Stack Overflow, then where can I ask questions about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the right site. While there isn't a tag for it *yet*, you can still ask about it. When you reach a [high enough reputation level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags), you will be able to create a new tag for it, but for now, you can just ask about it without the tag.

Comment: And it will not be closed?

Comment: @ArihanSharma it shouldn't if you ask a good question. It definitely won't be closed because you asked about DMOJ.ca

Comment: Thank you! It isn't letting me accept the answer right now, but I will.

Comment: I don't think there should be a tag for a website which does assesments or contests. The tag will be too meta to survive. We have a healthy hatred for any question that is a blatant copy of an assignment where the OP expects the SO regulars to solve the problem for them, see [project euler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275935) as an example. I doubt Stack Overflow is the right site without knowing the type of question the OP is going to ask. If it is a specific programming problem that is narrowly scoped and is a practical programming it should be fine but where it comes from is secondary.

Answer (score 7):

Even if SO had a `dmoj.ca` tag, that would not necessarily mean that questions about it were on-topic: some, many, most, or all might be close-worthy. (For example, the presence of a `facebook` tag on SO does not mean you can ask for help getting your profile fixed.) Likewise, just because an SE site, even a very mature one like SO, lacks a particular tag does not mean you can't ask about that subject on that site. It's possible that there just aren't enough questions yet to make the tag worthwhile, or, which is often more likely, the tag isn't descriptive enough of relevant questions on that site to be worth creating.

Here, I'm skeptical that a tag relating to the *original source of some arbitrary challenge* would actually have any real meaning on SO. SO cares about the actual coding problem, and if something unique about DMOJ.ca (some particular rule of judging, maybe) affects the problem, then that needs to be mentioned whether or not the tag is present. . . and if there's nothing unique to DMOJ.ca related to that particular problem, the tag is essentially meaningless.

A number of similar "example taken from a book or site" tags have already been burninated on SO in the past, and in fact [I wrote an explanation on MSO of why these tags are usually unnecessary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296829/whats-the-policy-on-creating-tags-for-website-names/296856#296856).